# GAE - a lot of /_ah/warmup startups in 1 second

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I created a GAE application. This worked fine till this morning...
There are still not so many request going to my application, but GAE regenerated my instance the whole time ...

Now when somebody comes to my site, first I do about 10 requests to the server to get some data, before this was done smoothly. Since today these 10 requests cause a lot of requests to /_ah/warmup as you can see below all within 1 second. This has as a result I came to my limit of "Frontend Instance Hours" without actually happening something.

So I wonder and hope somebody can give me an idea what can have caused this to happen, or how I can fix this issue,

Thank you,

```
2014-05-22 11:21:13.513 /_ah/warmup 200 7688ms 0kb module=default version=1
I 2014-05-22 11:21:13.512 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ

2014-05-22 11:21:13.093 /_ah/warmup 200 6838ms 0kb module=default version=1
I 2014-05-22 11:21:13.093 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ

2014-05-22 11:21:11.671 /_ah/warmup 500 5794ms 0kb module=default version=1
I 2014-05-22 11:21:11.670 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ
E 2014-05-22 11:21:11.670 Process terminated due to exceeding quotas.

2014-05-22 11:21:11.478 /_ah/warmup 500 5655ms 0kb module=default version=1
I 2014-05-22 11:21:11.475 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ
E 2014-05-22 11:21:11.475 Process terminated due to exceeding quotas.

2014-05-22 11:21:11.319 /_ah/warmup 200 5492ms 0kb module=default version=1
I 2014-05-22 11:21:11.319 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ

2014-05-22 11:21:10.403 /_ah/warmup 500 4587ms 0kb module=default version=1
I 2014-05-22 11:21:10.388 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ
E 2014-05-22 11:21:10.388 Process terminated due to exceeding quotas.

2014-05-22 11:21:10.310 /_ah/warmup 200 4494ms 0kb module=default version=1
I 2014-05-22 11:21:10.310 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ

2014-05-22 11:20:33.941 /_ah/warmup 200 7059ms 0kb module=default version=1
I 2014-05-22 11:20:33.941 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ

2014-05-22 11:20:33.698 /_ah/warmup 200 7106ms 0kb module=default version=1
I 2014-05-22 11:20:33.697 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ

2014-05-22 11:20:33.161 /_ah/warmup 200 6731ms 0kb module=default version=1
I 2014-05-22 11:20:33.161 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ

2014-05-22 11:20:12.854 /_ah/warmup 503 18ms 0kb module=default version=1

2014-05-22 10:19:51.619 /_ah/warmup 500 4085ms 0kb module=default version=1
I 2014-05-22 10:19:51.618 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ
E 2014-05-22 10:19:51.618 Process terminated due to exceeding quotas.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same errors. I saw the errors in the trace label but not in the logs. I asked in many places and finally received this answer:

> it appears that the 500 warmup errors you are seeing do not indicate
>   an error in your application. They are rather used internally as
>   signal messages in our architecture. That explains why you are not
>   seeing them in the Logs but only in Trace and why they are marked as
>   healthy messages. As Cloud Trace is still in beta it is understandable
>   to see minor inconsistencies.